# Setting SESSION variable in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Page1.php has a variable "flag" with value=1. When clicked, the javascript function "ajaxreq()" is called, and a text "Click me" appears below (ajax request from page2.php).

When clicked upon the appeared "click me", it calls "ajaxreq2(3)", and displays the text message "success". On clicking upon the displayed text message "success", the div content( id : displayLater) is set to display, which was hidden till now. This div has to contain the updated value of $_SESSION['tag'] in the $flag variable. How can i update it?

In this code, it gives out error : "undefined index 'tag' in page1.php".

In order to make use of the variable $_SESSION['tag'], I have to reload page1.php everytime. Otherwise, it remains uninitialized.
Is there a possibility that I can use the updated variable in page1.php?

page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$flag=1;
echo "<span onclick='ajaxreq()'>$flag</span>";
?>

<div id="page2contents"></div>

<div id="displayLater" style="display:none">
  <span>This is done.</span>
  <?php
   if(isset($_SESSION['tag']))
     $flag=$_SESSION['tag'];
  ?>
  <span onclick="displayNow($flag)">$flag</span>
</div>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
echo "<div onclick='ajaxreq2(3)'>Click me</div>";
?>
<div id="page3contents.php"></div>
```

page3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$tag=$_POST['tagger'];
$_SESSION['tag']=$tag;
echo "<span onclick='displayNow($tag)'>success</span>";
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT functions are as follows:

```
function ajaxreq()
{
  $("#page2contents").load("page2.php");
}

function ajaxreq2(x)
{
  $("#page3contents").load("page3.php",{tagger:x});
}

function displayNow(abc)
{
  abc=abc+2;    //some operation on abc
  $("#somethingToDisplay").show();   //displaying something else
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Is the error message unclear to you?

Comment: The message is clear to me. I need a workout to the problem.

Comment: well if the message would be clear to you, the workaround would be obvious I would say. So let me ask further: What makes it hard for you to write the workaround? Where to do you hit the roadblock?

Comment: It's the Session variable $_SESSION['tag'] in page1.php creating problems. Actually, the variable is initialized on page3.php, while I have its use on page1.php . That's why when loading page1.php, error pops that $_SESSION['tag'] has not been initialized!

Comment: And you can be sure that exactly that is the case. Otherwise PHP wouldn't gave you that error. Double check the session is started and the correct session name and session ID has been assigned to the request.

Comment: Yes, the session starts on loading the page. But, in order to make use of the variable $_SESSION['tag'], I have to reload page1.php. Otherwise, it remains uninitialized.

Comment: Well, that should be obvious. The browser has no idea that there's any PHP code behind that page. If you need to change what's displayed on page1 without reloading it you'll have to use JS code.

Comment: And what should that JS code be? I am unable to figure out a way to do this with JScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you

```
echo "<span onclick='displayNow('".$_SESSION['tag']."')'>success</span>";
```

And then

```
function displayNow(tag)
{
  $("#displayLater span").html(tag);
}
```

Comment: That is correct, but apparently I found out I needed something else on the code. I have updated the code as per required. I would be grateful if u have a look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#page3contents").load("page3.php",{tagger:x});
```

Will send variables to POST method. So you'll have to change the line in page3.php to :

```
$tag=$_POST['tagger'];
```

Comment: Sorry, I mis-typed that line. Have corrected it. But the main problem lies in initialization on $_SESSION['tag']. Please help with that.